# Does paypal no longer support and provide IPN facility for new websites?

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway

I've been using paypal IPN for developing ecommerce sites in the past. Its been now more than 1 yr since I last used paypal on any of my projects. But now when I wanted to setup Paypal for a new website I could no longer find the page where I could setup my PayPal IPN url. I tried logging in with paypal.com, sandbox.paypal.com and developer.paypal.com. And nowhere I can find a place to enter IPN url. Even with the sandbox account, I couldn't find the page where I could configure my store and enter the IPN url. Can any one help me find it or does paypal no longer provide IPN for processing payment for new projects?

Comment: This didn't help? https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/ ... seems its still there.

Comment: Yep I visited that page to. The doc gives instructions on how you can set up ipn handler. but when I login to my paypal account I can't find My Account > Profile > My Selling Tools menu in my dashboard. I can clearly remember I had setup IPN listener sigining up with sandbox account previoulsy (about a year ago.) but this time I'm unable to do so.

Comment: Well that is odd. I do admit I've not used IPN, I've just used the REST API with Webhooks (essentially the same thing, just more robust). Thing is, I've not found any mention that IPN is depreciated. Usually they have a red banner on their docs when something is "still supported for legacy sites, but not for new ones"... not finding that for IPN. So I understand your conundrum.

Answer (score 0):

try this link,   https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-ipn-notify and see if you can check your IPN

Comment: Hmm. that wroks for one of my paypal accounts but it doesn't work for another when I try for the Live one (removing sandbox from the url).

Comment: It works for me though both on live and sandbox. Can you clarify what "doesn't" mean on your case? Does it say handshake not verified? does it verify handshake but does not send IPN messages? there can be a lot errors regarding this that I've recently encountered as I'm also developing IPN for a project

Comment: I mean when I visit the url  https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-ipn-notify it takes me back to the dashboard with the business account I setup with my country as Australia. But when I visit the same url with my Paypal account setup with my country as USA I can get the page to enter IPN url. I want to setup IPN listener for the account setup with my country as Australia. I hope you get me now.

Comment: I do not know for sure but I believe this is already a geolocation problem by Paypal. I'll let you know if I find something else. Cheers